# Attach is not valid on a message with a non-multipart payload

Tags: python, email

I'm currently writing an application that needs to load an email into memory, add an attachment to it and send the same email back to the user. This has worked fine in the past, however I'm currently facing an issue where an email is sent in `Content-Transfer-Encoding` of `base64`.

I found a script online that converts a built in Python email message object to multipart, however whenever I do this, the original email doesn't get sent as base64 and now appears in plain text whenever I re-send the email.

Does anyone know how I could fix it? The (mostly redacted) email has been added and the code I used to convert the email to multipart. Thanks for the help in advance.

### E-Mail

```
# Before conversion
From: ██████████ <█████@██████.com>
To: ████████ <███████@██████.com>
Subject: █████████
Date: Fri, ██ ███ 2017 00:18:17 +0200
Content-Language: nl-NL
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0

cmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRy
ZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJl
ZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZA0K


# After conversion
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============0883378942=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: ██████████ <█████@██████.com>
To: ████████ <███████@██████.com>
Subject: █████████
Date: Fri, ██ ███ 2017 00:18:17 +0200
Content-Language: nl-NL
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0
--===============0883378942==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
cmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRy
ZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJl
ZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZHJlZGFjdGVkcmVkYWN0ZWRyZWRhY3RlZA0K
--===============0883378942==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.txt"
Hello world
--===============0883378942==--
```

### Plain to Multipart code

```
# If this method is not used on an email object
# A `TypeError` is raised with the message "Attach is not valid on a message with a non-multipart payload"

def mail_to_multipart(mail):
    """
    Convert an email to a multipart email
    :param mail: Email object
    :return: None
    """
    if mail.is_multipart():
        return mail

    mail_new = MIMEMultipart("mixed")
    headers = list((k, v) for (k, v) in mail.items() if k != "Content-Type")

    for k, v in headers:
        mail_new[k] = v

    for k, v in headers:
        del mail[k]

    mail_new.attach(mail)
    return mail_new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the issue was related to the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header not remaining in the old multipart block, by changing the following line:

```
headers = list((k, v) for (k, v) in mail.items() if k != "Content-Type")
```

To this:

```
headers = list((k, v) for (k, v) in mail.items() if k not in ("Content-Type", "Content-Transfer-Encoding"))
```

Fixed the issue